# How to retrieve Domain from Email Address in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

With Twig, how can we get domain from an email address which is a string?

```
<p>{{ app.user }}</p>
<p>{{ to_display_domain_name_here }}</p>
```

Where `app.user` is `xyz@gmail.com`

Want to retrieve domain `gmail` or `gmail.com` from this.

Comment: `app.user|split('@')|last` is the answer I could find (working even in case of multiple `@` in email address)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom twig filter and use regex to get domain.
Custom filter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html
Regex example: https://gist.github.com/Avidid/6114724

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it, in my opinion, would be create a custom Twig extension. You can find more info about how to do it in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

For a quick and dirty way I would probably use the [split filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) which actually behaves like an explode in Twig:

```
{{ app.user|split('@')[1] }}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it fails in case of multiple `@` in email address

Comment: I assumed you already validated the address during user's registration which is what you should do before saving an invalid address in your database.